# Send an e-mail. The proper way to express it

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request

What is the proper form?

send an e-mail

send a mail

send mail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it's not often that you'll find someone referring to email as "e-mail". Mostly there is no hyphen. Just a note!

To answer your question, definitely "**send an email**". As in:

> "I'm going to **send an email** over to Katelyn about that."

However, while this isn't wrong, it's actually most often shortened even more, to just "**email**" like this:

> "I'm going to **email** Katelyn about that."